# Sharing a declared array between two classes - Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

In good practice of OOP I am trying to separate some of my methods into two classes (not the main class).

Both classes require this particular 2D array so that the functionality of the program is executed correctly:

```
private char [][] board = new char[7][8];
```

I am unsure how to declare this within one class and be able to access it correctly within the following class so that the functionality is executed as intended.

```
public class DisplayBoard {


public void printBoard(){

for(int i=1; i<board.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<board[i].length-1; j++){
        if(board[i][j] != '\0'){
            System.out.print("| " + board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("|   ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("|");
}
System.out.println("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
     }
   }
```

My question is **how do I write/rewrite the declaration of this array in one class so that it can be accessed in both classes?**

The partial code from the other class is as following

```
public class Board {

    public void placeCounter(char player, int move){
        boolean placed = false;
        for(int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if(!placed) {
                if(board[i][move -1 ] == '\0') {
                    board[i][move -1] = player;
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: If both classes require the same array, should they really be separate classes?

Comment: "*In good practice of OOP I am trying to separate some of my methods into two classes*" - Who says that this is good practice?

Comment: You could implement a `toString()` method, or a `public char getBoardField(x,y)`, or a `public char[][] getBoard()`, possibly returning a copy to prevent modifications to the private board, or...

Comment: Given the update I'm still not sure why you want a separate class just for printing the board. What is the issue with having that method directly in `Board`?

Comment: It is for future use for when it is to be refactored for GUI etc.. the separation of the methods allows gameplay methods to be grouped together but apart from the actual game framework.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the two classes you mentioned, it looks like you have one Board class whose responsibility is to create and maintain the actual board configurations(in this case, positions) and other class whose responsibility is to just display in a specific format.

From a design perspective, the BoardPrinter class should be implemented as a strategy with a proper interface which takes the position array as input and then this BoardPrinter class should be injected in the Board class so Board class can call a specific strategy of printing when it wants to display itself. Something like this:

```
interface PositionPrinter {
    public void printPositions(char[][] board);        
}

class BoardPrinter implements PositionPrinter {
    public void printPositions(char[][] board) {
        // Do a Board specific printing.
    }
}

class Board {
    public PositionPrinter positionPrinter;
    private final char [][] positions = new char[7][8];

    public char[][] getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        positionPrinter.printPositions(positions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete but here is a method that shows how to access it.

```
public class Board {
    private char [][] positions = new char[7][8];

    //getters and setters

}

public class Another {
    Board board;

    public void printBoard(){
        board.getPositions();
    }

}
```

Comment: It can be ok, but depends on the actual relation between author's classes

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle You are true but event I don't really get what the question is. First he must update his question.

Comment: "*I don't really get what the question is.*" - Why do you write a speculative answer instead of asking for clarification in the comments?

Comment: @Turing85 Because question is speculative.

Comment: @hellzone ["*Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem. \[...\]*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @hellzone, how can `board` be set?